# Get icon of the default application that opens a file

Tags: android, icons, mime-types

I have the mime-type of a particular file.  I want to get the icon of the default application that opens the file.  So for music, I would display the Winamp icon if that was my default music player.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compose an intent with the given mime type and file URI and call [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) on it.

Something like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(fileUri);
intent.setType("image/png");

final List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo match : matches) {
    final Drawable icon = match.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
    final CharSequence label = match.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
}
```

Comment: I haven't been in to work because of the holiday so I'll post back Monday, thanks!

Comment: This worked to get the default icon.  When displaying in my app, the padding around the icon drawables is different.  I'm displaying them in a list so now I've got to figure out how to get uniform padding.