# Get icon from Mime type that looks exactly like icon in files app in Android

Tags: android, mime

I want to get the exact same file icon that the files app uses. I want to get the icon by `mime` type or extension. Is there any API that returns icon by `mime` type?

[I've tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248593/7024263) but it returns the icon of an app that handles that kind of file.

I want the icon like shown in this image:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only on Android Q and higher: [`getTypeInfo()` on `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getTypeInfo(java.lang.String)).

With luck, it will be added to `ContentResolverCompat`.

Comment: So you're saying there is no way I can get that icon? @CommonsWare

Comment: @kevintorch: You could rummage through the Q Beta source code, see where `getTypeInfo()` is getting its content from, and try to extract that into your own library. There is no official way to get those icons prior to Q that I know of, and bear in mind that various manufacturers may have tweaked the icon set.

Comment: the drawables they use are encoded....and not public...so I think there is no way I can get those icons